# Basic Tiny MCE File Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, tinymce, file-browser

I need a super-simple file manager (preferably in classic asp but not a deal breaker) that I can add to Tiny MCE v3.

It doesn't need to upload, show images or other media, just documents such as .pdf, .doc, etc.

I just need to allow the user to click a browse button beside a the link input box which will open the file browser window to the specified folder (always the same one), click the required file, the details of which will populate the input box.

I've seen a few as recommended elsewhere on Stack but these are either image/media only or I'm not bright enough to make them work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this question.

I found a TinyMCE/CKEditor plugin that really did the trick. It's called (surprisingly) PDW File Browser for TinyMCE and CKEditor and can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdwfilebrowser/.

It has a good range of different features and is really easy to modify (it has to be because it's me doing the modifications).

Definitely worth checking out.